# How can I get analog measurements from a National Instruments USB 6008 into a C# application without the use of measurement studio?

Tags: c#, measurement

I am a pretty green programmer, only having experience with scripting (mostly VBA and Python).  One of my professors has asked me to work on an application to operate a Laser Triangulation Scanner, in C#.  I know once I get raw voltage data in I can do everything else.  But I am a bit overwhelmed by the project as a whole and I can't seem to find any information on how exactly to get analog voltage data from the NI-USB-6008 without the use of Measurement Studio from National Instruments (I don't have $1000 to buy it).

Comment: Have you tried [NI-DAQmx](http://joule.ni.com/nidu/cds/view/p/id/2337/lang/en)?

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed NI-DAQmx (if you haven't please do!) there is an ActiveX and .Net DLL you can interop with that provides support for that device.  Details here:

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/F0FD13D2DD0C433986256D9C00468D29#NoMS

Example code locations for NI DAQmx here:

http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/5409#toc4

A whole tutorial here (skip to the .Net section):

http://sine.ni.com/nipdfgenerator/nipdfgenerator?pageURL=http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/5409&clientAppName=dz&dotsPerPixel=&dotsPerPoint=

Good luck!  NI stuff generally rocks across the board so you don't have to fish out lots of cash - but they'd rather you did.